# Exit CMD after batch file executes

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I tried `exit` and I tried putting a 2 second delay before `exit` but neither worked. After the bat file successfully runs, the CMD window will stay on.
I did notice however that a CMD window pops up and disappears right away and then the empty CMD window just stays there. (It's like there are two CMD windows)

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit
"C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe" --collection Replay, --profile Replay, --scene Scene, --startreplaybuffer --minimize-to-tray
exit
```

EDIT: Also removing the `cd` line doesn't make the batch file work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Not a solution but use `cd /D` rather than `cd`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window doesn't close because calling an app directly will tell the batch execution to wait for the app to close before running the next line. Use [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) instead. So your batch will be :

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit
start "" "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe" --collection Replay, --profile Replay, --scene Scene, --startreplaybuffer --minimize-to-tray
```

The exit is superfluous since after the end line it should close anyway. By the way if you're just looking to create something to click/call for launching OB studio with those parameters, using shortcut should be enough (put C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit on Start In and write the whole command and parameters on Target)

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get it to work when I tried putting the parameter on Target. Your method worked tho so thanks :)